# What is the best approach of creating a talking bot?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, bots

When creating a AI talking bot what kind of methods of design should I use? Should it be one function, multiple modules, should it have classes?

Comment: This question is *far* too vague the way in which it is currently phrased. Please clarify exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: What sort of AI? For a game? For talking? Help us out here.

Comment: Sorry guys, after re-reading it, it is vague. I'm asking what is the best approach of creating a talking bot? Should it be built off of if statements, classes, or something else? I just want to know how you'd guys go about creating a talking AI bot...

Comment: You may want to take a look at AIML http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AIML first.

Answer (score 0):

Understanding language is complicated, so the goal you need to determine first is what aspect of language you want to understand.

An AI must be able to understand what the person says to it, then relate it to what it already knows, and then generate a legitimate response.

These three steps can all be thought of as nearly independent, so you need to address each on its own.

The brain, the world's best language processor, uses a Neural Network, but that's not likely to work well for you.

A logic-based proof solving system, where facts that follow from facts are derived would probably work best, and I know of at least one system that uses it fairly effectively.

Answer (score 0):

I'd start with an existing AI program (like the famous Eliza) and run its output through a speech synthesizer.

Some source for Eliza is available [here](http://www.chayden.net/eliza/Eliza.html).  One open source speech synthisizer is [FreeTTS](http://freetts.sourceforge.net/docs/index.php).

If you're using a language other than Java, there are similar candidates AI bots and text-to-speech code out there.

Answer (score 0):

I've started to do some work in this space using this open source project called Talkify:
https://github.com/manthanhd/talkify

It is a bot framework intended to help orchestrate flow of information between bot providers like Microsoft (Skype), Facebook (Messenger) etc and your backend services. The framework doesn't really provide implementation for the bot providers yet but does provide hooks into its natural language recognition engine.

The built in natural language recognition library can be used to classify sentences to topics which you can then map to skill functions.

Give it a try! I'd really like people's input to see if how it can be improved.